# Interface 'DatabaseSnapshotDoesNotExist<T>' incorrectly extends interface 'DataSnapshot'

Tags: angular, firebase, npm, google-cloud-firestore, version-control

Im creating an angular webApp using firebase, i had some versioning problems yesterday but it got solved in the meantime. However, I tried using firebase database now and i got this error:
`Interface 'DatabaseSnapshotDoesNotExist<T>' incorrectly extends interface 'DataSnapshot'.`

This is my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.0.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/common": "^17.0.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.0.9",
    "@angular/core": "^17.0.9",
    "@angular/fire": "^17.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.0.9",
    "@angular/material": "^15.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.0.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.0.9",
    "@angular/router": "^17.0.9",
    "@firebase/database": "^1.0.2",
    "@fullcalendar/angular": "^6.1.4",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^6.1.4",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^6.1.4",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^6.1.4",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "^6.1.4",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^6.1.4",
    "events": "^3.3.0",
    "firebase": "3.9.*",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "type-stream": "^0.0.1",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.0.10",
    "@angular/cli": "~17.0.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.0.9",
    "@types/events": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.15.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~5.2.0"
  }
```

I tried downgrading typescript but angular 17 needs typescript 5.2.0

Would love any help, thank you!